# How to convert an sqldatareader in a table with specific structure in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, sqldatareader

I have an SQLDatareader that return data in the format:

```
58, A1
59, A2
60, A3
61, A4
62, B1
63, B2
64, B3
65, B4
66, C1
67, C2
68, C3
69, C4
70, D1
71, D2
72, D3
73, D4
```

This can continue for more records. 
I want to return those in a different order (both fields). Like this:

```
58, A1
62, B1
66, C1
70, D1
59, A2
63, B2
67, C2
71, D2
61, A3
64, B3
68, C3
72, D3
61, A4
65, B4
69, C4
73, D4
```

Is there a way to do it?

Thank you in advance, 
Dimitris

Comment: Its unclear what you're trying to ask. Are you just wanting to sort your results?

Comment: In your sql try `Order By YourOtherColumn`.

Comment: [MSSQL (T-SQL) ORDER BY statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: I believe that he is trying to sort the second column by the number, then the character so that B1 is before A2.

Comment: That is correct. I want to reorder them by having A1, B1, C1, D1 first and then A2, B2, C2, D2 and so on. So, it is not something that can be sorted on the SQL Server part.

Comment: Simply sort on the reversed string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is stated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

A `SqlDataReader` class:

> Provides a way of **reading** a forward-only stream of rows from a SQL
>   Server database.

That being said, *if you don't want to change your sql statement* or *if you don't allowed to do so*, you should first store your results in memory and then make that you want.

One option it would be to define a class like the below one:

```
// The name of the class is vague. Not knowing
// what your data represent, is quite difficult to 
// give a proper name.
public class Result
{
    public int Number  { get; private set; }
    public string Text { get; private set; }

    public Result(int number, string text)
    {
        Number = number;
        Text = text;
    }
}
```

Then I would define a list of object of type `Result`:

```
var results = new List<Result>();
```

After this in the `while` loop, where you read your data, I would create in each loop an object of type `Result`:

```
var result = new Result(..,...);
```

and then we add this at the `results` list.

At then end you would have a list of `Result` objects which you could sort as you wish. This could be done fairly easily using `LINQ`.

```
var results = results.OrderBy(result=>result.Text[1]).ToList();
```

You could check the above it this [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NRtdqP)